# Direct output from ant to powershell instance instead of cmd.exe window

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run ant from a powershell window.  When I run it, it launches a new cmd.exe window which disappears quickly and does not appear to run successfully.  Is there a way to run it directly in the powershell instance so I can see the output or redirect the output to the powershell instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd /c did what I needed.
Avoided it since this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#cmd_c_Using_the_old_cmd_shell) mentioned "This method should no longer be used with V3" but I'm guessing in a different context (example given is speed of `dir` command).

Also, updating the `PATH` environment variable with the ant path works.

Comment: You should be able to simply call `ant <target>` from a PowerShell console. Didn't open a new window for me when I ran a simple test build on my testbox. How exactly were you running `ant` before?

Comment: Yes, I was using the full path such as "c:\myAntHome\ant" or "& c:\myAntHome\ant".  If I edited the PATH environment variable, that works also.  Thanks.